# What are American politicians NOT allowed to do with the money they raise?

Tags: united-states, law, campaign-finance

Suppose candidate X raises, through whatever legal means, a million dollars for their campaign.  What, if any, ordinarily legal things does national law prevent them from spending this money on?

In particular, would a candidate be able to spend this money on stocks or other financial instruments (presumably, taking on some risk in order to hopefully accumulate more cash before election day)?

Notes:
It may be legal, but inadvisable to spend money on certain items - this is fine, my question is primarily concerned with legality.
State law may vary, so let's limit this to national rules.
Some assumptions may be required to answer this well - feel free to ask in comments or state them in your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the US campaign contributions [can not be used for personal use](http://www.factcheck.org/2008/11/personal-use-of-campaign-money/). So no, they can not *personally* buy stocks or other financial instruments. However, the *campaign* can invest legally. [Here's an example](http://www.politico.com/story/2012/05/sherman-invests-campaign-cash-075859).

Answer (score -2):

They are not able to do anything else than what they can do with it. The FEC website should have the rules of what they can do with campaign contributions.