# What would happen if a US presidential candidate used campaign cash for government purposes?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, campaign-finance

[Trump raises over $20 million in February with nearly $42 million in cash on hand, far behind Biden and Democrats](https://edition.cnn.com/2024/03/20/politics/fundraising-trump-campaign-biden/index.html)

US presidential candidates regularly spend millions of dollars every election to win the election. But if your goal is prosperity for the country, it seems obvious that there are more productive things to do with the money, such as pay down the US national debt. Granted the national debt is about $35 trillion, to which a few hundred million dollars will have no impact ... but something is still better than nothing.

Can candidates spend their campaign cash on ventures that benefit the country at large, like paying down the debt? Has anyone tried it before? If yes, what happened? If not, what would happen if they tried?

Related: [What are American politicians NOT allowed to do with the money they raise?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20028/what-are-american-politicians-not-allowed-to-do-with-the-money-they-raise) which suggests that candidates can legally use their campaign money this way.

Comment: people, including politicians are routinely donate money they get as prizes.

Comment: To be clear, in the 2020 election politicians altogether spent about $42 per US resident. That's a lot of money all told, but it's a big country.

Comment: Won't make a dent in the debt. OTOH he could use it for politically more useful purposes [to his base] like build a wall. There was one charity that even gathered money for that but there were some corruption lawsuit etc. thereafter, IIRC.

Comment: It's not obvious that it would be more productive to pay down the debt...Because the money that Trump and Biden spend is largely paid to *Americans*, who then have more money, and so pay more tax and also have more money to buy more things and so pay more tax etc etc.